# Como conseguir passar headers em requisição com Vue.js 2

Tags: http, vue.js, localstorage, vue-resource

Preciso passar o header `Authorization` que está localizado no `localStorage` com a chave de `iflix-user-token`, aqui está meu código:

```
getFilmes: function () {
    this.$http.get(Api.url + '/filme').then(
        response => {
            this.filmes = response.body
        }
    )
}
```

Estou a usar o `vue-resource`.

Answer (score 1):

Dando uma olhada na [documentação do vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#options), podes passar headers assim:

```
getFilmes: function () {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('iflix-user-token');
    this.$http.get(Api.url + '/filme', {headers: {'Authorization': token}})
      .then(response => this.filmes = response.body);
}
```

Comment: Eu procurei lá mesmo antes de pesquisar aqui, mas não obtive o sucesso. Porém, eu coloquei o Authorization sem aspas, irei tentar agora e retorno. De qualquer forma; Muitíssimo obrigado.

Comment: @MárcioLucas nesse caso as aspas não fazem diferença. Tens a certeza que é esse o nome do header que tens de enviar?

Comment: Sim, absolutamente. Realmente, não funcionou...

Comment: @MárcioLucas onde leste que precisas de passa esse header?

Comment: Irmão, eu consegui achar o erro. Passei o header. Resolveu. Obrigado!

Comment: @MárcioLucas ótimo! Se a resposta ajudou podes clicar para marcar como aceite.

Comment: Até queria mesmo, mas como sou novo aqui as minhas aceites não são contabilizadas.

Comment: @MárcioLucas aceitar não depende da votação. Pode dar uma olhada aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/129